# XQuartz will not start on Mac 10.9 Maverick - infinite failure loop

Tags: macos, xorg, osx-mavericks, xquartz

I've been having problems getting XQuartz to work on my Mac 10.9 (aka Maverick). I have installed and uninstalled XQuartz several times to no avail.

The error messages I'm getting from the Console.app is:

```
10/01/2014 15:01:21.148 org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[4821]: Xquartz: bootstrap_look_up(): Unknown service name
10/01/2014 15:01:22.099 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4675]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:22.099 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4675]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: giving up
10/01/2014 15:01:22.099 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4675]: /opt/X11/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Operation timed out
10/01/2014 15:01:22.099 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4675]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections /opt/X11/bin/xinit: server error
10/01/2014 15:01:22.106 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4675]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:22.392 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: xauth:  file /Users/chutsu/.serverauth.4830 does not exist
10/01/2014 15:01:22.854 org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[4975]: Xquartz: Unable to locate waiting server: org.macosforge.xquartz.X11
10/01/2014 15:01:22.860 org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.stub[4976]: Xquartz: Starting X server: /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11 --listenonly
10/01/2014 15:01:22.894 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: open terminal failed: not a terminal
10/01/2014 15:01:24.857 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: 
10/01/2014 15:01:26.859 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:28.862 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:30.864 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:32.867 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:34.870 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:36.873 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:38.876 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:40.879 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections 
10/01/2014 15:01:42.883 org.macosforge.xquartz.startx[4829]: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections
```

And it keeps on repeating forever. The code I used to remove XQuartz is as follows (in the terminal):

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist
sudo rm -rf /opt/X11* /Library/Launch*/org.macosforge.xquartz.* /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app /etc/*paths.d/*XQuartz
sudo pkgutil --forget org.macosforge.xquartz.pkg
```

Comment: Consider moving aside ~/.xinitrc, ~/.Xauthority, and ~/.Xresources to make sure nothing in those are troubling X?

Comment: I don't have xinitrc or Xresources at $HOME. Xauthority seems to be generated automatically. . . moving it didn't help. :(

Answer (score 3):

> Xquartz: bootstrap_look_up(): Unknown service name

That indicates that you did not logout and log back in as instructed to do by the installer.

But that should not be a fatal problem.

The most likely solution is that you have bad shell initialization scripts.  You can test this by doing:

```
sudo mv /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11{,.bak}
sudo mv /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11{.bin,}
```

After testing, you can undo that via:
    sudo mv /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11{,.bin}
    sudo mv /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11{.bak,}

Answer (score 2):

Are either your .bashrc or .profile exiting when non-interactive?

These symptoms are similar to those I have seen with my Mac OS Mavericks system. Numerous web searches show people with similar issues.  Some responses (where there were any) suggested "something is wrong with your .profile or .bashrc".  Mine looked, ostensibly, correct.

What I finally discovered was my .profile was 'source'ing my .bashrc and my .bashrc had an ancient test for interactivity:

`# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && exit`

Changing the "exit" to a "return" did the trick.

Comment: Moved my rc files to a different folder and still had the same problem.