# .serverauth.##### files repeatedly generating/appearing then deleting/disappearing every few seconds, how to diagnose this issue?

Tags: macos

.serverauth.##### files repeatedly generating/appearing and deleting/disappearing in macOS Mojave 10.14.4 Home directory every few seconds

[image: .serverauth.##### files repeated generating/appearing and deleting/disappearing in Home directory every few seconds]

How to diagnose this issue?

Comment: X11 server generates them. Quit X11.

Comment: @Tetsujin I couldn't find any process whose name contains "x11" in Activity Monitor

Comment: look for xquartz. I can't find anything specific for Mac, as it's really a nix thing, but see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199160/what-are-serverauth-files-in-my-home-directory or https://superuser.com/questions/699838/xquartz-will-not-start-on-mac-10-9-maverick-infinite-failure-loop

Comment: No lucky with xquartz